# How do I extract -30 days from this time format

Tags: python, time

Hello I am working on predicting some values and for that I need to access all values in past 30 months. However in my `timedate`, there is a value of `1527505282` and I am wondering how to I get an actual date from this. `1527505282` should be equal to `28.05.2018 18:07:30` with format: `dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss`.

Could anyone please help me understand what format of time is this and how do I get to `dd-mm format` in python? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This type of time is called epoch

```
import time
time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.localtime(1527505282))
```

or

```
import datetime 
datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1347517370).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

For UTC

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(1527505282).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Since you only want to get 30days data may be you could simply subtract that many days .

in epoch 1 day = 86400
for 30 day = 86400*30 = 2592000
so you could use

```
timestamp = 1527505282 - 2592000
if timestamp<=1527505282:
```

SO this would ensure your data is in this range

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
from datetime import datetime
timestamp = 1527505282
date_obj = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)
print(date_obj)
date_str = datetime.strftime(date_obj, "%d-%m")
print(date_str)
```

Output:

```
2018-05-28 16:31:22
28-05
```